# How to execute a part of a (text)file?

Tags: linux

So I'm looking for a command on Linux that would let me execute a file as binary, but skipping the first x bytes, so:

```
$ echo "some text" > file
$ cat /bin/bash >> file
$ ??? file  # should run bash
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this is probably the closest you will get:

```
dd if=container.txt of=executable bs=<bytes to skip> skip=1
chmod +x executable
./executable
```

Comment: Not quite was I was hoping for, but I think you're right about it being the best I can do.